# Postman no response when php run get_magic_quotes_gpc()

Tags: php, postman, php-7.4

My php version is 7.4. 
When run postman to test my api, it return message

> Could not get any response

(I did turn off my SSL certificates and proxy.)
Hence, I went thru apache error logs and I found error like the following:

> PHP Deprecated:  Function **get_magic_quotes_gpc()** is deprecated in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpstormProjects\api\db\mysqli.php on line 108

Then I remove the code `get_magic_quotes_gpc()` and finally my postman work.
Anyone know how to let postman ignore PHP Deprecated warning? I had try to turn off Deprecated in error_reporting but it doesn't work.

Comment: The documentation suggest not to use get_magic_quotes_gpc, and it seems like a better idea to not to use this particular function. If you want to escape there are other alternatives

Comment: thanks.. i had chg my php version to 7.3.

Comment: Well, that's a temporary measure.